# Delphi: how to adjust ownerdrawn Listbox, for various system DPI?

Tags: delphi, listbox

Delphi7. I have Listbox, OwnerDrawn, with fixed ItemHeight. Now i want to make it look OK on 125% Windows font sizes. Currently i see that items font is increased but ItemHeight isn't, so items are "truncated" by Y.
How to adjust ItemHeight when OS has 125% or 150% font sizes?

Comment: I think this is unanswerable unless you post a bit of sample code. How are we to guess what you're doing? Secondly, I believe you need to scale your ItemHeight to handle the text height of the font you want to draw, since the ItemHeight is in pixels not dialog units.  I would use a Canvas.TextHeight('X')+Padding to get the height and store it into the ItemHeight. (Padding = 4 to 6 pixels)

Comment: @Warren P
Thanks, using Canvas.Textheight is good too. I solved below.

Comment: @Ingo, using `TextHeight` was also a point of my answer... You've declined it just because you want to adjust the item height somewhere else because you're using different list box style. Never mind...

Comment: @TLama, thanks for your answer too. I didn't decline Ur answer, site did it.

Answer (score 1):

Can't use OnMeasureItem as List.Style=OwnerDrawFixed.
My sol:

```
function ScaleFontSize(Size: Integer; Form: TForm): Integer;
begin
  Result:= Size * Form.PixelsPerInch div 96 + 1;
end;

procedure TfmSetup.TntFormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with ListTabColors do
    ItemHeight:= ScaleFontSize(ItemHeight, Self);
end;
```